# Mongoengine: Querying against reference field returns no results, but field is valid on object

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

Simplified, I have two Documents, a Package and a Target. A Package contains lists of DBref() to the Targets and the Targets contain a DBRef to the Package. Simplified it's set up like so:

```
class Target(Document):

    package = ReferenceField('Package')
    name = StringField()


class Package(Document):

    targets = ListField(ReferenceField('Target'))
    name = StringField()
```

When I create one set of Targets the standard way using mongoengine things work as expected:

```
# in a method on Package, self = current Package instance
target = Target(name="My Name", package=self).save()
self.targets.insert(0, targets)
```

I can query across Targets by that package and it returns results as expected:

```
>>> p = Package.objects.get(id='53e4db7bc57d207fc3d70738')
>>> Target.objects(name="My Name", package=p)
[<Target: My Name>]
```

BUT for certain Targets we are creating a lot at once and instead use a bulk execute to create the documents (simplified):

```
bulk = Target._get_collection().initialize_unordered_bulk_op()
for line in csv_reader:
    entry = dict(zip(header, line))
    entry.update({'name': 'My Name', '_cls': 'Target', 'package': package.to_dbref()})

    bulk.find({'name': 'My Name', 'package': package.to_dbref()}).upsert().update({'$set': entry})

bulk.execute()
```

Theses objects appear totally normal at glance, however, queries referencing their packages do not work even though reading their values seem to work without issue.

```
(Pdb) self
 <Package: Video Package 53e3edc7c57d2079436a14c9>
(Pdb) Target.objects(name="My Name", package=self)
[]
(Pdb) Target.objects(name="My Name")
[<Target: My Name>]
(Pdb) Target.objects(name="My Name")[0].package
<Package: Video Package 53e3edc7c57d2079436a14c9>
```

Even doing a `to_json` the objects seem to look comparable:

```
>>> bad_target.to_json()
'{"_id": {"$oid": "53e4334cd2f370649dce5e20"}, "_cls": "Target", "package": {"$oid": "53e4334cc57d207f0a86a3c7"}, "name": "Bad Target"}'

>>> good_target.to_json()
'{"_id": {"$oid": "53e4db7bc57d207fc3d70739"}, "_cls": "Target", "package": {"$oid": "53e4db7bc57d207fc3d70738"}, "name": "Good Target"}'
```

It seems fairly clear that the `bulk` operation is the likely culprit here, but as far as I can tell it's being done correctly and normal operations such as retrieving the reference Package object work as expected, but queries will just not return anything. Any ideas or suggestions would be very much appreciated!

---

***Update with new info***

Using a raw pymongo query yields some more interesting results:

```
>>> Target.objects(__raw__={"name": "My Name", "package": p.to_dbref()})
[]
>>> Target.objects(__raw__={"name": "My Name", "package": p.id})
[<KeywordTarget: My Name>]
```

This seems to give more indication that it's the nature in which the Targets are saved that are indeed the issue.

Comment: Do you have a reproducible test case? Does it work if you use regular inserts and not bulk inserts?